# Drupal Multi Site Installation - Extract site

Tags: drupal

I have been landed with a Drupal installation that is on a server that is about to be taken down.  My initial thought was to just transfer the contents of the server and then the import the sql database.

I have done this hundreds of times with WordPress installations and from reading up on Drupal it seemed to be essentially the same process.

What has thrown me now though is that upon delving into the Drupal installation is that there is a folder called /sites which contains loads of different websites.  I am assuming this is a Drupal Multi Installation?

Can someone explain to me the basic process I would need to go through to get just one site out of this setup and put it on a new server?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward (in theory, at least):

1. Download a copy of Drupal, place it in the web root on the new server
2. Copy the database to the new server
3. Copy /sites/example.com on the old server to the new one, but rename it /sites/default
4. Copy /sites/all to the new server
5. Edit /sites/default/settings.php on the new server, update the db connection info to match the new database

The only caveat there is that the version of Drupal you download should match the version installed on the old server. If it's out of date, you should update ASAP as there have been some critical security patches recently.

Comment: Thanks Clive, i'm going to attempt it now.  Seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: I left out a pretty major part (oops!) please see the edit. You might also need to copy profiles from the /profiles folder if the site was installed with a non-standard profile